# Cast int to enum in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do you efficiently cast an int to enum in javascript?

Say I have this enum

```
enuTable = // Table enum
{
    enuUnknown: 0,
    enuPerson: 1,
    enuItem: 2,
    enuSalary: 3,
    enuTax: 4,
    enuZip: 5,
    enuAddress: 6,
    enuLocation: 7,
    enuTasks: 8,

};
```

In part of the code I get a return value from an AJAX call that is a number corresponding to one of the above tables.

I can write a switch transforming the value, however is there a more efficient (briefer) way of casting an int to enum? One reason is, I don't want to constantly have to change the switch, in case I change the enum. I guess I could use an array with the enum names and construct an identifier to index into the enum, however again, I would need to change the array every time the enum is changed. I guess what I am looking for is a transparent method, that doesn't require beforehand knowledge of the enum.

Comment: I would take a look to my answer, because I feel it'll give you a more generalized solution for your actual code ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this

```
var keys = Object.keys(enuTable).sort(function(a, b){
    return enuTable[a] - enuTable[b];
}); //sorting is required since the order of keys is not guaranteed.

var getEnum = function(ordinal) {
    return keys[ordinal];
}
```

**UPD:** Is some ordinal values are absent you can use

```
var keys = Object.keys(enuTable).reduce(function(acc, key) {
    return acc[enuTable[key]] = key, acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Your edit is **quite important**. Also, this definitely works for the OP's enum. But in the case that not all integers in a range are included (in the OP's example, 0 to 8 are all included), this wouldn't work exactly. Say they left out a few (who knows why), this method would not return the correct one

Comment: I would add that what would happen if enumeration isn't 1,2,3,... but 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16.... I find your answer lacking something.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yeah, I was actually just thinking of that - I recently saw posts on SO about using that. I forget why that scheme was used though...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: thx for pointing this out. I've added the more robust version.

Comment: One additional question pops up trying to use this, the function returns the enum property correctly, however how do I prefix it with enuTable, so I can use it later on in comparisons etc? i.e. getEnum(2) should return enuTable.enuItem.

Comment: @aggaton Do you mean you are going to replace `enumTable` values with something? `enumTable.enumItem = {blah: 'blah'}`?

Comment: No, like this var foo = getEnum(2); if (foo == enuTable.enuItem) { ... } else { ... }

Comment: I think you don't need `getEnum` for comparison. You can simply compare `var foo = 2; if(foo == enumTable.enuItem){/*...*/}`

Comment: @Ian: I believe 1, 2, 4, ... was used to achive the following result `var idx = 1, en = {none: 0, first: idx, second: idx*=2, third: idx*=2}, firstOrThird = en.first|en.third;` Now one can check `if(firstOrThird & en.third) {/*go*/}` while `if(firstOrThird & en.second) {/*no go*/}`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Yes! That's what it was!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be something like the following:

```
 function toTableName(i) {
     for(var p in enuTable) {
         if(enuTable.hasOwnProperty(p) && enuTable[p] === i) {
              return p;
         }
     }
     throw new Error('that\'s no table...');
}
```

Comment: `var p` I think :) and `if(enuTable.hasOwnProperty(p))`

Comment: I'll ask you the same question as above, the function returns the enum property correctly, however how do I prefix it with enuTable, so I can use it later on in comparisons etc? i.e. toTableName(2) should return enuTable.enuItem.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'use it in comparisons etc'? I don't quite follow :-)

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to truly turn it into an enum, like this: var foo = toTableName(2); if (foo == enuTable.enuItem) { ... } else { ... }

Comment: Well, you can't really, because the enuTable is really just a regular object, but enuTable.x resolves to a number, so you could just compare it with 2 without doing anything to it at all. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, JavaScript doesn't have enumerations like C# has built-in.

Thus, I believe that if you receive an AJAX numeric-based identifier and you want to code a `switch` statement, you don't need to *cast* to `Number` in JavaScript, because your switch will compare your pseudo-enumeration property value:

```
switch(ajaxNumber) {
   case enuTable.enuPerson: 
      break;
}
```

If you're looking for obtaining the enumeration value label (for example `enuPerson`) the following code should be enough (check out a working sample in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9C45/1/)):

```
// We're going to implement a basic enumeration prototype to generalize
// what you're looking for so you may re-use this code anywhere!
function Enum(valueMap) {
    // We store the enumeration object
    this._valueMap = valueMap;
    this._valueToLabelMap = {};
    var that = this;

    // This will create an inverse map: values to labels
    Object.keys(valueMap).forEach(function (label) {
        that._valueToLabelMap[valueMap[label]] = label;
    });
}

Enum.prototype = {
    // Getting the whole label is as simple as accessing
    // the inverse map where values are the object properties!
    getLabel: function (value) {
        if (this._valueToLabelMap.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
            return this._valueToLabelMap[value];
        } else {
            throw Error("Enum instance has no defined '" + value + "' value");
        }
    }
};

var enuTable = new Enum({
    enuUnknown: 0,
    enuPerson: 1,
    enuItem: 2,
    enuSalary: 3,
    enuTax: 4,
    enuZip: 5,
    enuAddress: 6,
    enuLocation: 7,
    enuTasks: 8,
});

// Now, if we provide a number, the fancy Enum prototype will handle it
// so you're going to get the whole enumeration value label!
var taxLabel = enuTable.getLabel(45);
```

Comment: I like your suggestion, however I was going for something smaller latching onto the existing enum mechanism in javascript, I would have to modify all places where the enum is already being used.

Comment: @aggaton maybe a find all/replace with a regexp would be enough :D

Answer (score 0):

I love Yury Tarabanko's solution, but it took me some time to understand what it does (including reading and understanding about reduce(). I can't comment on you @YuryTarabanko, but how did you come up with this?

The solution I whould come up with, is this one. You can access it the same as Yury's solution (keys[ajaxResponseNumber]). I tested it with jsPerf and this is faster in Firefox, but that's not relevant in this case.

`var keys = {};
for (var x in enuTable) {
 if (enuTable.hasOwnProperty(x)) { keys[enuTable[x]] = x; }
}`

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask you the same question as above, the array indexes the enum property correctly, however how do I prefix it with enuTable, so I can use it later on in comparisons etc? i.e. keys[2] should return enuTable.enuItem, not just enuItem...

Comment: "but how did you come up with this?" - we have an array of keys and are going to convert it to something else (object in this particular case). Ideal case to use `reduce` or `reduceRight`. Functional approach cough, cough :)

Example `var sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce(function(running, item){return running + item}, 0); //6`